# Facebook SDK Upgrade to OAuth - PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to upgrade our PHP implementation of Facebook SDK for login according to http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/. The changes explained seem easy enough, change session references to user. However there was one small piece missing, the 'next' url param has been replaced by 'redirect_uri'. I ended up with infinite redirects until I found and changed my 'next' url param.

Now, for the Javascript SDK, I noticed the only difference between our current FB.init and the FB.init explained @ http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ is the 'oauth: true' addition. So I added this to our javascript and refreshed. When I click the FB like button I noticed that headers are not calling oauth like the PHP SDK does, instead it goes straight to login.php which is what I thought was the pre 3.0 behavior. Is our javascript SDK in compliance with the oauth addition?

Also, there is a note at the bottom of http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/ saying "All apps must utilize the new OAuth flows by September 1." Does this mean that if we don't upgrade our FB logins will no longer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback about the 'next' and 'redirect_uri' parameters; we'll look into updating the documentation.

Regarding OAuth compliance, as long as you're loading the JS SDK from http://connect.facebook.net, e.g. http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js you'll be in compliance with the appropriate standards.

Regarding your second point - you have until October 1 to migrate to OAuth 2.0 as described on the [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/). After this time, your FB logins will fail with an error.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You may want to update the post @ http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/ at the bottom where it says "All apps must utilize the new OAuth flows by September 1" from sept to october so others don't get confused.

Comment: Wow. It also seems that you guys changed another param. Before 3.x we were using 'req_perms', but now with 3.x it was changed to 'scope'. Because of this we ended up creating several hundred accounts in our system with no email address b/c user was not being prompted to accept whether we could access their email.

Comment: I was not aware of this; I'll look into it. Thanks again for reporting.