# Error when including redirect_uri with getLoginUrl (Facebook PHP SDK)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I want the user to be redirected to a particular webpage after logging in using Facebook. I created a `LoginUrl` using Facebook PHP SDK and the user clicks on this link to log in. I followed http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/ when using the `$facebook->getLoginUrl()`

**Problem**: If I were to include the `redirect_uri` parameter, Facebook gives me an error `An error occurred. Please try again later.` The login url works fine without including the `redirect_uri`.

Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

**Non-working PHP Code**

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
        "redirect_uri" => "http://mydomain.com/login/facebook"
    ));
```

**Working PHP Code**

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
    ));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had this [same exact problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262936/facebook-sdk-upgrade-to-oauth-php-and-javascript). FB changed the parameter from `redirect_url` to `next` from v2 to v3, and is poooooorly documented. Try `next`, should work for you.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I tried using `"next" => "http://mydomain.com/login/facebook"` and now there is no longer any error, but after clikcing on the `Go to App` button, the user does not get redirected to the new url...

Comment: The `next` param is used when facebook is done with it's work, logging the user in. When complete, facebook uses this param to redirect the user to the url you specify. So when you click the `go to app` button, it should log the user into facebook right?

Comment: yea... its not so smart that Facebook say you can use redirect_uri (with i instead L) for redirect after you log in, but it doesnt work, I still have no idea either...

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty old topic, but here is the solution I've found working, if someone reads it later... First thing is that you have missed the comma after "redirect_uri" in your "Non-working PHP Code". And if you have "App on Facebook" selected in your application settings (app in Canvas) then your redirect_uri must be the same as the url you have set for Canvas App. If you are using just Page Tab, the redirect_uri can be anything.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    "scope" => "email,user_education_history,user_work_history",
    "redirect_uri" => "http://mydomain.com/login/facebook",
));
```