# Codeigniter login with facebook return userId 0 , After login success and redirect back to my side

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-login

I have developed login facebook app(Facebook SDK) with codeigniter, Firstly, I do in my local.

It's working well, when do login successful, facebook redirect back by redirect_uri to my side controller,and get userId to query information of user logged.

But, when I upload this code to Server side, redirect_uri is worked, but I get return 0 of userId, so , if userId 0, I can't query data of users logged.

My question is, why userId return 0 , after login succeed?

Code Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Setting extends CI_Controller {

       public function __construct()
       {   

          $CI = & get_instance();
          $CI->config->load("facebook",TRUE);
          $config = $CI->config->item('facebook');
          $this->load->library('facebook', $config);

       }
       public function index() 
       {
             if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

                 $this->acc_login();
             }else {
                 redirect('check_session', 'refresh');  
             }
       }

       public function acc_login()
       {
             $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

             if($user) {

             try {              
                  $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/me');
                  redirect(base_url());             
             } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
                  echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars(print_r($e, true)).'</pre>';
                  $user = null;
             }
             } else {
                    $param = array('scope' => 'email,read_stream','redirect_uri' => $my_url);
                    $data['getURLLogin'] = "<a href=\"".$this->facebook->getLoginUrl($param)."\"><img src=\"".base_url()."public/frontend/images/login-fb.png\" width=\"155\" height=\"25\" /></a>";

             }
       }

    }

?>
```

Comment: You need to add your code snippet so we can help.  Without a code sample, it's hard to figure out what problem you are facing.

Comment: I post the code snippet already, any solution please

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
```

before

```
$user = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

**UPDATE**

FB changed the parameter from "redirect_url" to "next" from v2 to v3, and is poooooorly documented. Try "next", should work for you.

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332666/error-when-including-redirect-uri-with-getloginurl-facebook-php-sdk)

Comment: Sorry for such question but.. did you add your domain name to application settings on facebook?
https://developers.facebook.com/apps
Check your application's site url.
"App Domains:" - your domain + your domain with "www".
"Website with Facebook Login" - your domain

Comment: I didn't put www at before my domain name, because it is sub domain

see the Site URL- http://test.mydomain.com

Is it not correct?

Comment: while you are on application's settings page:
1) App Domains = mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com 
2) Website with Facebook Login = http://test.mydomain.com

Comment: Are your "Sandbox Mode" is on? If yes, add yourself as a developer of this application or set off "Sandbox Mode"

Comment: My app Sandbox Mode: is disabled

Comment: FB changed the parameter from redirect_url to next from v2 to v3, and is poooooorly documented. Try next, should work for you. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332666/error-when-including-redirect-uri-with-getloginurl-facebook-php-sdk)

Comment: Actually, when I login with facebook, redirect_uri is working well, but my userId still get 0 ID forever, and I take a look at my site url ,It is also have facebook url,
It mean facebook have been logged already, I try a new tab and type facebook.com, yes, facebook already logged.

Why do I got 0 id if facebook have logged?

And I try to click login again, facebook return my true ID without fill username and password.

So, event login two time, it's going corrected !

Comment: If you is logged in facebook this doesn't mean that your application is connected to your account. Go to http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&ref=mb -> ads, apps and sites -> apps you are using, click change settings -> do you see your application there?
If it is there remove it and try to connect again. If it is not there check/recopy api keys.